# changing before pseudo element on hover

Tags: html, css, hover, transition, box-shadow

So i managed to create a inset shadow on an image, after reading around the web..

it works, but i cannot make it change on :hover.

Currently i have:

```css
.shadow {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.shadow::before {
  border-radius: 100%;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  transition: box-shadow .2s ease-in-out;
}

.shadow:hover:before {
  box-shadow: inset 5px 5px 55px rbga(0, 0, 0, .8);
}

.shadow img {
  float: left;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=1015">
</div>
```

I have put the code here: `https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rRwGmV`

I hope some of you know how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: typo issue `rbga`

Comment: yup i see it now

Comment: Lol thanks.. how stupid, i've looked over  the css so many times now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```css
.shadow {
 position: relative;
 max-width: 100%;
 float: left;
 }
    
    .shadow::before {
        border-radius: 100%;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 8px red;
        transition: box-shadow .2s ease-in-out;
    }

.shadow:hover::before {
    box-shadow: inset 5px 5px 55px green;
}
    
.shadow img {
   float: left;
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 300px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="shadow">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=1015">
</div>
```

Comment: The issue was solved because of a typo, but i gave you the answer because yours was the closest what it is supposed to do. This might help someon else that needs this :)

Comment: ya i checked that later

Answer (score -1):

what do you think about do it without `:before`?

```css
.shadow img{
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}

img:hover {
      box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px red;
}
```

```html
    <div class="shadow">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=1015">
  </div>
```

[Here is my codepen whith this code](https://codepen.io/dever/pen/eXRGLJ?editors=1100)

Did I forget to do something? How can I improve?